# Why is this javascript code not disabling the button?

Tags: jquery, button, input, javascript

How do we disabled buttons in javascript/jquery?

I tried:

```
$('#imgupload').disabled=true;
```

and

```
$('#imgupload').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

but neither works. Right after the above I put a `console.log` line that works, so I know the surrounding code is fine.

The only thing that disables my button is if I hard code that it's disabled like this:

```
<input type='submit' id='imgupload' value='Upload' disabled=disabled />
```

But I need to enable and disable it dynamically on certain events so I can't use that.

Comment: For the difference between `prop()` and `attr()` see the excellent discussion at [.prop() vs .attr()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab DOM element here:

```
$('#imgupload')[0].disabled = true;
              --^-- // DOM element
```

Or use `prop`:

```
$('#imgupload').prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using prop() :

```
$('#imgupload').prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

prop() should do

```
$('#imgupload').prop('disabled', true);
```